# XmlhttpRequest getting the redirection link?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to open `www.example.com/redirect.php?uid=XXXXXX`
Using this :

```
 Var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
 req.open('GET', link):
 req.send(null);
```

But I get an error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load "redirected link here"`
When I open it in the browser and follow the network traffic, in the response header of my link in the location attribute I find the redirected link, and it is the same one the error above says he can't load it, is there a away to stop the redirection and get the link in the location?

I also tried `req.open('GET', link, false);` But I get a network error.

Comment: have you tried `var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders()`?

Comment: Yes I did but I do get empty string :/

Comment: @Mugiwara, `getAllResponseHeaders()` would return the headers sent by the final (redirected) Url, so it's useless. HTTP redirections are supposed to be transparent to the final user, and that's why you can't really know whether they are happening or not.

Comment: @OscarPaz yeah you are right, i didnt think about the domain thing ^^;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost surely, the 'redirect link' is in another domain, so you can't load it via AJAX requests, and that's why you're receiving an error. I don't think you can capture the final link of the redirection, as XMLHttpRequest handles HTTP redirections automatically, just like the browser does.

Comment: Yes it is another domain, so it is impossible?

Comment: It is not impossible ... if the remote domain allows cross-domain requests by sending `access-control-allow-origin` headers, which I suppose it's not doing. Most sites don't, precisely to avoid other sites accessing their content this way.

Comment: @OscarPaz OP is asking if he can stop the browser from automatically redirecting the request so he can get the `Location` header from the initial response. It wouldn't matter if the subsequent responses had CORS headers because it is still impossible to stop the browser from redirecting.